# Speed up JS and jQuery functions on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there some way to speed up some JS and jQuery functions on mobile website,like textillate and some normal `onClick` functions (like `fadeIn`, `fadeOut` etc.)?

Comment: What do you mean by "speed up"?  Is this a question about performance or a behavior?  What are you expecting to get out of this answer?

Comment: For an example my slideToggle function is working just fine on desktop ,but on mobile there is a slight delay and sometimes that div just opens 
without any effect.I hope you understand my problem here :)

Comment: Dont use jquery animations. Use css transitions / keyframes or something like gsap or animejs but the build in jquery `.animate()` is garbage.